# Scrollbar with grid getting errorcannot use geometry manager pack inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am newbie in Python
error on putting scrollbar  screen says

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\JAG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1558, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\bankatmPython\main.py", line 122, in log_in
        create_account_screen()
    File "C:\bankatmPython\main.py", line 387, in create_account_screen
        scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
    File "C:\Users\JAG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1999, in pack_configure
        + self._options(cnf, kw))
    _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
```

can someone please let me know what I am doing fishy in below code

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()

  scrollbar = Scrollbar(win)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
mylist = Listbox(win, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set ).grid(row=3)
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. In the context of the error message, "." means "the root window". You can't use both `.grid` and `.pack` in widgets that have the root window as a master.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks Bryan, Here is the solution


scrollbar = Scrollbar(win)
transactionText = Listbox(win, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
transactionText.grid(row =0, column=0)
for line in range(100):
transactionText.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
scrollbar.grid(sticky=E, row = 0, rowspan =10, column = 11, ipady = 1000)
```